# Mongodb not listing collections when connecting remotely from CentOS

Tags: mongodb, windows-10, centos6, remote-connection

Mongo server: Windows 10 (host)
client: CentOS 6.2, a virtual box vm on windows 10 host. This is actually a cloudera quick start vm.
Issue:
mongodb connects to the remote server (from CentOS to Windows) via terminal, lists the databases fine, but 'show collections' just returns blank. That said, the collections are accessible because I can query any collection and the count also gives me the correct results.
On the other hand, I have connected to the same mongo server from IntelliJ and it shows all the collections just fine.

Just curious as to why this is happening.. Any comments?

Side Note: is there a mongodb command to count the number of collections in a database?

Thanks

_Vamsi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are using the database you want to show the collections for.  You may be using a database that doesn't have any collections.

```
> use desiredDatabase
> show collections
```

If the list is still empty, try signing in with an admin user account.  The user needs to be able to perform the `listCollections` action.  The [`dbAdmin`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/built-in-roles/#dbAdmin) role includes the `listCollections` action.

To get the count you can use the `getCollectionNames` function which returns an array and you can get the length from that.

```
> db.getCollectionNames().length
```

Comment: Thanks Logan. Of course I'm using the right database. The second piece of information is good. Tahnks for that.

Comment: If you create a collection from the terminal does it show up?  E.g. `db.collection.insert({a:1})` then `db.getCollectionNames()` shows `collection`?

Comment: I can add a collection, no issues. But 'show collections' and db.getCollectionNames() both show blank. However, i can query the new collection just fine though. Weird.

Comment: Must be because the user you sign in with doesn't have appropriate permission.  I'll update the answer.

Comment: Logan: Now I'm able to access the collections. My hunch is at that time, may be i was using the default `test` collection and did not actually switch to the needed collection. Thanks for your response.